# Swagger UI shows camelCase parameters instead of PascalCase

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using NewtonSoft.json in Asp.Net Core 3.1 API with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 5.3.3.

By default in Asp.Net Web API, 2 input and output parameter case was PascalCase.

Now I am migrating to .Net Core API in which default case is camelCase.

So I changed it to use PascalCase by adding below code in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
            })
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                // Use the default property (Pascal) casing
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });//Configure Newtonsoft as JSON serializer.
```

But in the Swagger UI, it is showing input and output parameters in camelCase while the API's response contains values in PascalCase.

I Googled but found a method in AddSwaggerGen DescribeAllParametersInCamelCase() which turns all the parameters into camelCase.

Is there DescribeAllParametersInPascalCase() method?

**How can I configure Swagger/Swashbuckle to show input/output parameters in PascalCase?**

Here's an example:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure the JsonSerializerOptions like this:

```
.AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null)
```

---

Example:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers()
.AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: I wanted camel casing and didn't want to rely on any "defaults", so instead setting this to `null`, I set it to `System.Text.Json.JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`.

Comment: Where do I put this? On which object do I call .AddJsonOptions?

Comment: To AddController().AddJsonOptions()

Comment: Works good for property names, not for dictionary keys though .
You can also set `JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;` but it only works for the actual response, not for the example generated by SwaggerGen.

Comment: it does not fix the problem

Answer (score 7):

If you are still using `Newtonsoft.Json` in Asp.Net Core 3.1 instead of the new defualt `System.Text.Json`.

Once you configure Newtonsoft for Asp.Net Core 3.1 by:

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => {
  // My config is Pascal Case
  x.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
});
```

You need to also install `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft` and opt in by adding the following after `services.AddSwaggerGen(...` :

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();
```