# How to change JSON schema generated by Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

By default, in ASP.NET Web API apps swagger generates JSON-schema in which class field names start with a lowercase letter. For example, for this class:

```csharp
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
    }
```

the following schema will be generated:
[image: schema]

How to configure it so that the field names in schema exactly match the names in the C# code?

I read this document from Microsoft ([ASP.NET Core web API documentation with Swagger / OpenAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-6.0#openapi-specification-openapijson)), but did not find the answer

Comment: what problem do  you face because of this case change in schema ?

Comment: Which implementation are you using `NSwagger` or `Swashbuckle` anyway you could change the `jsonserializer` options
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61405727/swagger-ui-shows-camelcase-parameters-instead-of-pascalcase

Comment: @jjchiw, thank you very much! indeed, adding this JsonSerializer option helped - `.AddJsonOptions(opt => opt.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null)`

Comment: @CodingMytra, there were problems with deserialization on the client side

Comment: you mean you have another client who is using this json file for listing your API's ?